# What's the impact if you terminate a SHRINK SPACE CASCADE operation halfway?

Tags: oracle, space, cascade, tablespace, shrink

I understand that space are reclaimed periodically during the operation as I see the spaced used reduced even before the entire operation is over. I tried to search online for any impact if you terminate the operation halfway due to expiring maintenance window.

Thank you very much.